# Drupal: Ajax post getting internal server error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, drupal

I cannot figure out why the following is giving out internal server error. I can see on console log that I am getting the value, but I can not pass it for some reason.

```
mav_id = document.getElementById("mav_id");
var teamName  = mav_id.value;


 jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
     url: 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/sites/all/modules/insert.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:  teamName,

    success: function (obj, textstatus) {
                  if( !('error' in obj) ) {
                      yourVariable = obj.result;
                  }
                  else {
                      console.log(obj.error);
                  }
            }
});
```

PHP

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['teamName']) or isset($_POST['data'];))
    {
   connector info
        }

      $sql = 'INSERT INTO [mydb].[dbo].[team]
    VALUES (2,3)';
    mssql_query($sql, $link);
    }
    else 
      $sql = 'INSERT INTO INSERT INTO [mydb].[dbo].[team]
    VALUES (0,0)';
    mssql_query($sql, $link);
    ?>
```

All I get is:

> POST http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/sites/all/modules/insert.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: So check your server logs to see what's wrong. Why are you posting the code we can't run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of this line (the extra semicolon):

```
if(isset($_POST['teamName']) or isset($_POST['data'];))
```

change it to:

```
if(isset($_POST['teamName']) or isset($_POST['data']))
```

I'm also not sure why you don't have `{}` for your else and why you have connector info between the if I'm guessing you don't have that in your actual script?

Comment: True. Sorry messed the code up editing it here. You were right. Thank you so much. I did not notice the syntax error myself